# "} expected" error in c# program

Tags: c#

I have made two classes in C# but when I created the constructor for the second class it gave me the error "} expected" I don't understand what is wrong as there are enough sets of {}. It also gives the same error for the very final curly brace at the bottom of the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c1 = new Car("Audi","A1","AB12 CDE",1985, 15000);
            Console.WriteLine(c1);
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Fleet
    {
        public Fleet()
        {
            public Car[] carArray = new Car[100];
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Registration { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }

        public Car(string make, string model, string registration, int 
year, int value)
        {
            Make = make;
            Model = model;
            Registration = registration;
            Year = year;
            Value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Make: {0}\nModel: {1}\nRegistration: {2}\nYear: {3}\nValue: {4:C}", Make, Model, Registration, Year, Value); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This line `public Car[] carArray = new Car[100];` is invalid inside the constructor - move it outside of it

Comment: Next time: Hovering with the mouse over a curly will show the closing one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your class

```
class Fleet
{
    public Fleet()
    {
        public Car[] carArray = new Car[100];
    }
}
```

you have `carArray` declared public but it's in the constructor.  You can't have modifiers in methods.  Any variable declared in a method is always only seen in the scope of that method.  I'm assuming you need it in the class and not the constructor so just move it out like so...

```
class Fleet
{
    public Car[] carArray = new Car[100];

    public Fleet()
    {
    }
}
```

and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

Above, in the "Fleet" class inisde the constructor you have tried to created an array object  "carArray" along with initialization. 
Because of this you are getting this error.

The constructor are meant for initialize the class variavles/objects, not for declaration of variavles/objects.

Try for this, it will work.

```
class Fleet
{
    public Car[] carArray = null;
    public Fleet()
    {
        carArray = new Car[100];
    }
}
```